# Compare dataframe column with strings and numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns that have strings and numbers. When I compare the two columns, they don't match even though they appear to be the same.

example data:

```
old_code     new_code
100000       100000
```

When I compare, the result is false:

```
df['old_code'] == df['new_code']
0    False
dtype: bool
```

The datatypes are the same:

```
df.dtypes
old_code    object
new_code    object
dtype: object
```

I tried stripping the columns in case there is whitespace but they still don't match:

```
df['old_code'].str.strip() == df['new_code'].str.strip() 
0    False
dtype: bool
```

I made the dataframe into a dictionary to see if I could spot anything amiss and I noticed that for some reason one of the columns is formatted as a string and the other an integer:

```
d = df.to_dict()
d
{'old_code': {0: '100000'}, 'new_code': {0: 100000}}
```

Any suggestions on how to compare these columns? I don't want to change the data type to integer since some of the rows are truly strings.

Comment: You'll have to convert both to the same type for comparison purposes.

Comment: How about?  `str(df['old_code']) == str(df['new_code']) `

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### `object` dtype series can hold anything

The issue is `object` dtype series contain **arbitrary** Python objects. Here your series have a string in one and an integer in another:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'old_code': ['100000'], 'new_code': [100000]}, dtype=object)

print(df.dtypes)
# new_code    object
# old_code    object
# dtype: object

print(type(df['old_code'].iat[0]))
# <class 'str'>

print(type(df['new_code'].iat[0]))
# <class 'int'>
```

Therefore, be consistent. Convert both to numeric *or* both to strings.

#### Convert to numeric

```
cols = ['old_code', 'new_code']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

#### Convert to strings

```
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda s: s.astype(str))
```

#### Without modifying your dataframe

Strictly speaking, you don't *need* to update your dataframe. You can caste each series for comparison purposes only:

```
# numeric comparison
pd.to_numeric(df['old_code']) == pd.to_numeric(df['new_code'])

# string comparison
df['old_code'].astype(str) == df['new_code'].astype(str)
```

Comment: Great answer, I would only add that it's not necessary to replace the data for the comparison, `df['old_code'].astype(str)==df['new_code'].astype(str)` returns `0    True` without actually changing the data in place

Comment: @G.Anderson, Great point, i'll add that suggestion. Though, *possibly*, OP may *want* to be consistent here :)

Comment: Agreed, tough to say without the desired use-case, but for strictly _how do I compare_, it's viable. Cheers!

Comment: Good  one @jpp +1

Answer (score 1):

What about using numpy:

convert to int:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df['old_code'].astype(dtype=np.int64)
0    100000
Name: old_code, dtype: int64
```

convert to float:

```
>>> df['old_code'].astype(dtype=np.float64)
0    100000.0
Name: old_code, dtype: float64
```

convert to string:

```
>>> df['old_code'].astype(dtype=np.str)
0    100000
Name: old_code, dtype: object
```

`DataFrame.apply()` can be used with `pd.to_numeric`

```
>>> df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
   old_code  new_code
0    100000    100000
```

Comment: IMO, it's good practice to prefer the new-style `pd.to_numeric` as it has useful `downcast` and `errors` arguments. But otherwise, yes, these are other ways to convert series to different types.